# bundle the sails application into single executable

Tags: sails.js

Need help to compile the sails project into single executable(exe) for windows and linux. I already tried with [pkg](https://github.com/zeit/pkg) and [nexe](https://github.com/nexe/nexe). Both working with single js file, But not working with sails project.
Need your help guys

Comment: whats your need to do this?

Comment: Need to convert my sails application into native application like exe in windows. similar apps in mac and linux

Comment: hi , did you find a solution for it ?